# Custom action in WooCommerce order form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding a custom action to the order page that prints a shipping label  from a third party API here's my code so far:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_actions', 'tcs_woocommerce_order_actions', 10, 1);

function tcs_woocommerce_order_actions($actions) 
{
    $actions['tcs_print_label_action'] = __("Print shipping label");

    return $actions;
}

add_action('woocommerce_order_action_tcs_print_label_action', 'tcs_print_label', 10, 1);

function tcs_print_label($order) 
{
    ?>


        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Shipping Label</title>
            <style>

            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <img src="/example-label.png" alt="" />
            <script>
                window.print();
                //window.history.back();
            </script>
        </body>
        </html>

    <?php


    // Do something here with the WooCommerce $order object
}
```

I'm going to add custom code to contact the API and get the label but can anyone tell me a better way to print the label and then redirect back to the order form?

Comment: From which API you are going to print labels ?

Comment: I'm using DPD but I can handle that much, the API will return the label itself to be sent to the printer. I just need to get wordpress to do it and then make it's way back to the order page